# jQuery DOM inside form is not updating in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a django template with the form:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <form class="myform">
        <div class="title"></div>
        Some form element

    </form}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm getting the form in jQuery like:

```
var infoForm = $(this).next('myform');
```

to update the `title` class, i do this:

```
infoForm.find('title').html('<div class='my-title'>My title</div>');
```

But it doesn't update the DOM,

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: what is `$(this)` refers to? Are you using it inside an event?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
('.myform');
```

instead of

```
('myform');
```

and

```
('.title')
```

instead of

```
('title')
```

See [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: sorry that was a type.. I have used `.myform` and `.title`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
infoForm.find('title').html('<div class='my-title'>My title</div>');
```

Does this work?

```
$('.title').addClass('my-title').removeClass('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$('.myform').first().find('.title').text('My Title');
```

or

```html
$('.myform').get(0).find('.title').text('My Title');
```